# Redis local.xml <automatic_cleaning_factor>

Tags: redis

Currently I have redis installed and have a few questions I hope someone can help me with?

1. In the local.xml I have the tag:

   ```
    <automatic_cleaning_factor>0</automatic_cleaning_factor><!-- Disabled by default -->
   ```

If I change the 0 to 1 will it automatically do a flush of my cache when required?
(Kinda like flushall from redis-cli?)

2. in redis.conf:

I'm going to put the following settings:

maxmemory 256mb
maxmemory-policy allkeys-lru

(Which I found from a wordpress config site).

Also is mentioned here : http://redis.io/topics/config

Does this make sense for Magento if I'm just using Redis as a cache?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is from https://github.com/colinmollenhour/Cm_Cache_Backend_Redis

> Automatic cleaning is optional and not recommended since it is slow
>   and uses lots of memory. Occasional (e.g. once a day) garbage
>   collection is recommended if the entire cache is infrequently cleared
>   and automatic cleaning is not enabled. The best solution is to run a
>   cron job which does the garbage collection. (See "Example Garbage
>   Collection Script" below.)

You should run a cron if needed rather than using that tag